# Looking for title of story, probably sci-fi, about mentally declining man who built prompts allowing him to perform daily functions. Any help here?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, technology, soft-sci-fi, novella

I have no idea when it was written, nor when I read it, but it's been at least a couple of decades My memory is very vague on particulars, just that it seemed to be pretty prophetic, bringing to mind technology today, particularly pertaining to the advent of smartphones. But don't recall the mechanisms that reminded the man where to be and what to do in day-to-day life. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: I recall this. He's suffering from dementia and builds an artifical intelligence to basically test his responses. Eventually he instructs it to replace him.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233352/man-creates-ai-copy-of-himself-gets-dementia-commits-murder-suicide-while-wife?

Comment: Yes, that's it! I didn't recall "dementia" being specifically mentioned, but that's definitely the story, thank you.

Comment: Your vague description sort of matches R. A. Lafferty's Hugo-winning story ["Eurema's Dam"](https://archive.org/details/MindWebs_201410/070+Eurema's+Dam+-+R.A.+Lafferty.wav).